# sql windowing a dynamic pool of dates

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table discharge 
(
id number
discharge date
);

Table created.

insert into discharge values(1606905792457620, '06-DEC-15')
insert into discharge values(1606905792457620, '20-DEC-15')
insert into discharge values(1606905792457620, '06-JAN-16')
commit;

create table visit 
(
id number
visit date
);

Table created.

insert into visit values(1606905792457620, '08-DEC-15')
insert into visit values(1606905792457620, '19-DEC-15')
insert into visit values(1606905792457620, '30-DEC-15')
insert into visit values(1606905792457620, '11-JAN-16')
insert into visit values(1606905792457620, '17-FEB-16')
commit;
```

The requirement is that each unique discharge requires two unique visits.  Each visit can only apply to one discharge.
So while there are two visits greater than the 06-JAN-16 discharge, only one hasn't been applied to a previous discharge.
I've tried rank and row_number but I can't figure out how to 'window' the visit dates which are
1. greater than the discharge date  and
2. haven't been applied to other discharges

Here's how I need them numbered:

```
id                      discharge          visit 
1606905792457620     1  06-DEC-15   1  08-DEC-15  
1606905792457620     1  06-DEC-15   2  19-DEC-15
1606905792457620     2  20-DEC-15   1  30-DEC-15
1606905792457620     2  20-DEC-15   2  11-JAN-16
1606905792457620     3  06-JAN-16   1  17-FEB-16
```

Thanks in advance for any and all replies.

Comment: This would be so much easier if the visit table showed which discharge it was linked to. Is it not possible to get that information added into that table? Presumably, that information is known at the point at which the visit is added?

Comment: I totally agree; unfortunately (for me), the visits are captured separate from the discharges.  I'm beginning to think that it's the only way I can get this done.  Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get to without getting into the complicated realms of the `MODEL` clause is:

```
select id,
       discharge,
       visit,
       row_number() over (partition by id, discharge order by visit) rn2
from   (select d.*,
               v.visit,
               row_number() over (partition by v.id, v.visit order by d.discharge desc) rn1
        from   visit v
               inner join discharge d on (v.id = d.id and v.visit >= d.discharge))
where  rn1 = 1
order by 2, 3;

               ID DISCHARGE  VISIT             RN2
----------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 1606905792457620 06/12/2015 08/12/2015          1
 1606905792457620 06/12/2015 19/12/2015          2
 1606905792457620 20/12/2015 30/12/2015          1
 1606905792457620 06/01/2016 11/01/2016          1
 1606905792457620 06/01/2016 17/02/2016          2
```

You could argue that if a visit happens after two discharge dates that it belongs to the latest discharge, rather than the one before?

Comment: Of course there are several where that's happened.  I'm going under the assumption of the opposite.  Visit dates apply to 'unallocated' discharge dates.

Comment: This is the problem with not storing which discharge the visit is linked to. You might have situations where an earlier visit is skipped, or it might just be delayed. Or you might have 3 visits for the same discharge; how are you meant to know which is which? I would highly recommend that the design is changed!